# Upgrading GlassFish 3.1.2.2 to use JPA 2.1

Tags: jpa, glassfish, jpa-2.0, glassfish-3

I am working with GlassFish 3.1.2.2  (I can not upgrade to 4 due to OS restrictions).

I'm interested in upgrading JPA 2.0 to JPA 2.1 GlassFish 3.1.2.2. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Did you have any success with this? I've also hibernate 4.3.5 upgrade going on and we are still using glassfish 3.2.2. I'd to replace javax.persistence.jar which got me working but we have multiple clusters and after upgrading this jar, my job dispatcher app deployment fails with weird issue of 'EJB Timer Service is not available'. What jars you had upgraded for this ?

Comment: I could not upgrade GF 3 to use JPA 2.1, JPA 2.1 require JDK 7
so you have to use GF 4. Regarding your issue may be its not related to JPA but to EJB version. For example if you user EJB light the timer service will not be supported

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is most likely not possible at all. JPA 2.1 is part of EE 7 and therefore not fully integrated with EE 6 GF 3.1.2.2.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try just replacing the EclipseLink and JPA jar files in Glassfish?

It will probably work, but if you use managed persistence units they will not expose any JPA 2.1 API, you would need to unwrap the EntiyManager to access these.

Comment: Yes I tried to replace the eclipseLink and JPA jars under <GlassFish_Home>\glassfish\modules, and while I am using managed persistence it did not work as you wrote.
and I dont know how to unwrap the EntitiyManager to access it these.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Hibernate 4.3.8 (requires JPA 2.1) with Glassfish 3.1.2.2.

*Note: I'm not using any services provided by glassfish. All the libraries I use are in the WEB-INF/lib.*

1 - Override all JPA classes (package `javax.persistence`) in `glassfish/modules/javax.persistence.jar`  with JPA 2.1 version. You should **not replace** the entire JAR, only override the classes. This JAR has an OSGI manifest and other classes that must remain there.

2 - Remove all javassist classes (package `javasssist`) from `glassfish/modules/weld-osgi-bundle.jar`. This solves a possible incompatibility if you are using Hibernate.