# Facet JPA 2.1 is not supported by the server in glassfish

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, glassfish-3

I am working in a web application which uses glassfish, maven...etc
When I am adding projects to glassfish server it is saying like the error

```
 Facet JPA 2.1 is not supported by the server.
```

[image]

Glassfish version is 3.1.2,
   Jdk version is 1.7
   Jpa facet i am using 2.1,
   Eclipse luna

How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

From [glassfish documentation](https://glassfish.java.net/downloads/3.1.2-final.html)

> Welcome to GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2, the
>   production-ready application server supporting the **Java Platform**,
>   **Enterprise Edition 6 (Java EE 6)** standard.

As reported from [wikipedia history of Java EE editions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_EE_version_history#Java_EE_6_.28December_10.2C_2009.29) **Java EE 6 supports only JPA 2.0**, so is not possible to use JPA 2.1

Answer (score 0):

Glassfish 3.1.2 [supports JEE 6](https://glassfish.java.net/downloads/3.1.2.2-final.html) but JPA 2.1 is [part of JEE 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_EE_version_history#Java_EE_7_.28June_12.2C_2013.29). 
Even so, there's a user on SO that reports he used JPA 2.1 in GF 3.1.2 (see last post): [Upgrading GlassFish 3.1.2.2 to use JPA 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18447541/upgrading-glassfish-3-1-2-2-to-use-jpa-2-1)