# using JPA 2.1 with Glassfish 3.1 : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.EntityManager.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery

Tags: jpa, stored-procedures, plsql, glassfish, jpa-2.1

I am using Glassfish 3.1.2.2 (which uses JPA 2.0). I would like to call PL/SQL stored procedures in JPA 2.1. I have an Oracle database.

How can I do that ?

My pom.xml :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

I’ve put the eclipselink-2.6.0.jar and javax.persistence-2.1.0.jar in the glassfish lib directory :
glassfish-3.1.2.2\glassfish\domains\domain1\lib

Persistence.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="pu_is" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>${persistence.datasource}</non-jta-data-source>    
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
     <property name="eclipselink.target-server" value="SunAS9"/>
     <property name="eclipselink.logging.logger" value="x.jpa.EclipseLinkLog"/>
     <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="${persistence.logging.level}"/>
     <property name="eclipselink.logging.timestamp" value="false"/>
     <property name="eclipselink.logging.session" value="false"/>
     <property name="eclipselink.logging.thread" value="false"/>
     <property name="eclipselink.logging.exceptions" value="false"/>
     <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="Oracle"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit> 
</persistence>
```

I have also tried with persistence version="2.1" and the corresponding ...persistence_2_1.xsd.

At run time, I obtained an error :

## {mb.createMessage}: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.EntityManager.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/persistence/StoredProcedureQuery;

```
@ManagedBean(name = "mb")
@ViewScoped
public class MessageBean implements Serializable {
  private String selectedTypeMessage;
  private String selectedSector;
  private Date selectedIncidentDate;
  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    this.selectedIncidentDate = new Date();
  }
  public void createMessage(){
        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("pu_is");
        EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        StoredProcedureQuery query = em.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("MsgNew");
        query.setParameter("P_DTE_INCIDENT",this.selectedIncidentDate.toString());
        query.setParameter("P_TYPE_MESS",this.selectedTypeMessage);
        query.setParameter("P_SECTEUR",this.selectedSector);
        query.execute();
   }
  // getters/setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name="mytable")
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
  name = "MsgNew", 
  procedureName = "MSG_NEW", 
  parameters = { 
    @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = String.class, name = "P_DTE_INCIDENT"), 
    @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = String.class, name = "P_TYPE_MESS"), 
    @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = String.class, name = "P_SECTEUR")
   }
 )
public class MessageEntity implements Serializable{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer id;
 }
```

Comment: Have you read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18447541/upgrading-glassfish-3-1-2-2-to-use-jpa-2-1

Comment: Yes, but it didn't help me. I want to use JPA 2.1 only for this project.

Comment: As the JPA jars are on the server classpath, Glassfish will not work with a 2.1 jar.  the best you can do is unwrap the EclipseLink EntityManager from within the Glassfish Entitymanager proxy and access its 2.1 methods directly.  Or upgrade your server to one that supports JPA 2.1