# Spring : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven

I'm developing with SPRING

My pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>4.0.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.3.4.Final</hibernate.version>
    <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
    <version.servlet-api>3.0.1</version.servlet-api>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<name>springdev</name>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.javaconfig</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-javaconfig</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.m3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        <!--exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

My dispatcher.xml

```
<!--
-->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/pourtest" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

The error

```
Grave: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
 ////
 Avertissement: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
```

I already try the exclusion  I commented  in pom.xml but  error persist

Comment: do you use jboss as application server? this error typically means that in your classpath there are conflicts between hibernate jpa 2.0 and 2.1. Hibernate 5 uses jpa 2.1.

Comment: i use glassfish! i know tha it jpa conflict but i dont know where

Comment: glassfish 3 maybe?

Comment: yes, i use glassfish open source 3.1.2.2

Comment: resoleved by using hibernate version 3.6.0

Comment: if you can't upgrade the application server this is the other solution, but you loose the functionality of jpa 2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the answer at this question.

[Upgrading GlassFish 3.1.2.2 to use JPA 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18447541/upgrading-glassfish-3-1-2-2-to-use-jpa-2-1)

It says that glassfish 3.1.2 uses java EE 6 that does not support jpa 2.1.
The problem is the application server you have to upgrade it, if possible.